# Intent not sending right data on next activity from ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, tags, baseadapter

I made one **ListView** with **ImageView** and **TextView**.
When I click on **image** then by using **intent** i pass **Image uri** and **text** to next activity.Now for first **four cells** of listView i am getting right data on next activity.But when i **scroll the listView** and then *click* on some cell of listview then the *wrong data* will be sent.So if anyone knows the solution then please post it...
*thanks in advance*

Here is my code of adapter class..

```
 public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
private Activity mActivity;
public ArrayList<Data> mObjects;
// /private final Context context;
Context context;

static class ViewHolder {
    static ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    TextView name;
    TextView review;
    DownloadImageTask mTask;
    String ab[];
    // DownloadImageTask1 mTask1;
    // ImageView photo;
}

public Adapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {

    this.mActivity = (Activity) activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.mObjects = mObjects;

}

public void setObjects(ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {
    this.mObjects = mObjects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Data item = mObjects.get(position);
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        // viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        viewHolder.review = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());
    holder.name.setText(item.getmConcatinate());

    holder.review.setText(item.getmreview());
    holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ab);
    // holder.photo.setBackgroundResource(0);
    holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);
    if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
        holder.mTask.execute();
    }

    ViewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
            //Object tag=   v.getTag();
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data","abc");
            String title = item.getmConcatinate();
            String picture=item.getmImageUrl();   


            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LargeView.class);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try444444"); 
                intent.putExtra("data", title); 
                Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try555555"); 
                intent.putExtra("image3",picture);
                Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try66666666"); 
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try7777"); 
        }
    });

    // holder.mTask1 = new DownloadImageTask1(item.getmImageUrl1(),
    // holder.photo);
    // if (!holder.mTask1.isCancelled()) {
    // holder.mTask1.execute();
    // }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return (this.mObjects.size());
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return (this.mObjects.get(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return (position);
}

public AbsListView.RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener = new RecyclerListener() {

    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        DownloadImageTask imagetask = viewHolder.mTask;
        // DownloadImageTask1 imagetask1 = viewHolder.mTask1;
        if (imagetask != null) {
            imagetask.cancel(true);
        }
        // if (imagetask1 != null) {
        // // imagetask1.cancel(true);
        // }
    }

};
```

}

Code for next activity...

```
  public class LargeView extends Activity {
//ImageView image4;
//Bitmap bm1;
//String image_url;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_large_view);
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView  image4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.largeimage);
    //Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back99);

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try12121212112");
    String easyPuzzle = intent2.getExtras().getString("data");
     String image_url= intent2.getExtras().getString("image3");

     text.setText(easyPuzzle);
     BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions1;
        bmOptions1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions1.inSampleSize = 1;
        LargeImage large=new LargeImage();

        Bitmap bm = large.LoadImage(image_url, bmOptions1);
       image4.setImageBitmap(bm);

     Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", image_url);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I modify getView() it will produce desire result
// set position as tag to the view and retrieve the data in onclick

```
   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Data item = mObjects.get(position);
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        // viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        viewHolder.review = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());
    holder.name.setText(item.getmConcatinate());

    holder.review.setText(item.getmreview());
    holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ab);
    // holder.photo.setBackgroundResource(0);
    holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);
    if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
        holder.mTask.execute();
    }

    ViewHolder.icon.setTag(position); // update position because list view recycle

    ViewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
            //Object tag=   v.getTag();
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data","abc");

            int clickedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();

            Data clickedItem = mObjects.get(clickedPosition);

            String title = clickedItem.getmConcatinate();
            String picture=clickedItem.getmImageUrl();   


            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LargeView.class);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try444444"); 
                intent.putExtra("data", title); 
                Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try555555"); 
                intent.putExtra("image3",picture);
                Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try66666666"); 
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try7777"); 
        }
    });

    // holder.mTask1 = new DownloadImageTask1(item.getmImageUrl1(),
    // holder.photo);
    // if (!holder.mTask1.isCancelled()) {
    // holder.mTask1.execute();
    // }

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: You did not store position. Listview recycle the view so set tag to clicked view

 ViewHolder.icon.setTag(position); // update position because list view recycle

and retrieve the vlaue in onclick methods thatis  passed to next activity

int clickedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();

 Data clickedItem = mObjects.get(clickedPosition);

Comment: can i ask you one more question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535175/after-parsing-the-images-in-imageview-of-listview-are-not-the-right-images

Comment: also some of the imageurl are null but still for that imageview some random images are loading.

Answer (score 2):

In this method:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
        //Object tag=   v.getTag();
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data","abc");
        String title = item.getmConcatinate();
        String picture=item.getmImageUrl();   


        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LargeView.class);
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try444444"); 
            intent.putExtra("data", title); 
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try555555"); 
            intent.putExtra("image3",picture);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try66666666"); 
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try7777"); 
    }
```

item is going to be whatever you set it to last.

You need to store your ViewHolder somehwere else and use the view tag to store the item.  Then you can use item = v.getTag in this routine.

Alternately, you can subclass your view and have it store the tag for use in the onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you define onClickListener as an anonymous class. The item that you use in the class can be anything.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final Data item = mObjects.get(position);
View rowView = convertView;

if (rowView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    viewHolder.icon.setTag(position);
    // viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    viewHolder.review = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
}

ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());
holder.name.setText(item.getmConcatinate());

holder.review.setText(item.getmreview());
holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ab);
// holder.photo.setBackgroundResource(0);
holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);
if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
    holder.mTask.execute();
}

ViewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
        //Object tag=   v.getTag();
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data","abc");
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());
        Data itm = mObjects.get(pos);
        String title = itm.getmConcatinate();
        String picture=itm.getmImageUrl();   


        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LargeView.class);
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try444444"); 
            intent.putExtra("data", title); 
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try555555"); 
            intent.putExtra("image3",picture);
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try66666666"); 
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try7777"); 
    }
});
```